# Adding border changes width relative to parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following CSS:

```
.subtask {
  background: var(--offwhite-color);
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: .625em 1.25em;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: .9em;
}

.subtask.highlight {
  border-left: .3em solid var(--secondary-color);
}
```

where `.subtask.highlight` is only rendered `onClick()`. However, this extends the width past the fixed width compared to when the `.highlight` wasn't rendered. I'd like the width to stay the same, but add the border as is on the left side. How can I accomplish this?

Looking in dev tools, it seems like none of my specifications are being overriden, so I'm wondering what's going on.

Comment: try to add transparent border to subtask class  .subtask{border-left: .3em solid transparent;}

Comment: A common trick that i used to use is to set the border to transparent so the width will always be the same across different state

Comment: According to your comment below Jaswinder's answer, you appear to be confused/surprised, that the element width has changed by adding a border. You should go read up on how the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model) works then, that should give some clarity. (And also explain what to do about your current issue here.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add transparent border to **subtask** class

```
.subtask {
      background: var(--offwhite-color);
      margin: 0.3em;
      padding: .625em 1.25em;
      width: 60%;
      margin-left: .9em;
      border-left: .3em solid transparent;
    }
    
    .subtask.highlight {
      border-left: .3em solid var(--secondary-color);
    }
```

Comment: I see. It now extends past the 60% that other components were relying on though

Answer (score 0):

Try to add box-sizing: border-box;

```
.subtask {
  background: var(--offwhite-color);
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: .625em 1.25em;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: .9em;
}

  .subtask.highlight {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: .3em solid var(--secondary-color);
}
```